# Validating groups of check-boxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I'm generating check-boxes based on suggestions in a table which has 30 rows per page. A row can have 0 suggestions or it could potentially have a 100. I want to use jQuery to only allow a user to select one check-box. If they select one and then change their mind the original check-box is unchecked and the new one become checked.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should be using radio buttons instead. As a UI convention, most users expect to be able to check multiple boxes, but only select one radio button. (However, another UI convention is that if you have more than about six selections, you should use a dropdown.)

Comment: @Blazemonger  I should have wrote I'm using a custom X-editable, that's why I'm using check-boxes. When I click on a check-box the value of that checkbox gets written to the database. I essentially need to get each group of check-boxes and make sure only one value is selected.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `radio` inputs.

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
```

**Make sure that one group of radio inputs has the same name!
Giving them different names means you will be able to select multiple radio inputs:**

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio1" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio2" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio3" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio4" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio5" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio6" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="testRadio7" value="Test"/>Test</label>
```

Which is undesirable.

If you really want checkboxes, use the following CSS:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;    /* Firefox */
    -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="testRadio" value="Test"/>Test</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion above, but in case you don't feel like doing so you can achieve the same with the following code;

```
<script>
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).prop( "checked", false );
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
</script>
```

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9kxoc2g6/1/

Comment: How can I validate for groups of check boxes though. Each row may or may not have suggestions. All of the suggestions are independent of each other.

Comment: @LukeOsborne in that case you can add an id to each row of checkboxes. So using `each()`, you can check for each row of checkboxes which checkbox is currently empty. I could try editing @killstreet's answer but if he knows what I'm talking about he'll probably edit it himself. Unless you want me to do it. :)

Comment: @RizkyFakkel  I'd appreciate it if you could, been at work for 13hrs and my eyes are killing me. If  a row has checkboxes it's inside this `<ul class="unstyled inline" check-box-group="@item.EntityId" >`

Comment: @LukeOsborne Do the rows have any specific class or ID? `unstyled inline` look like very generic classes that you might have used anywhere.

Comment: @RizkyFakkel I was trying to write a function to get all the Id's of the row's that have checkboxes [Js Function](http://i.imgur.com/xdiXCym.png) The row Id is @item.EntityId. This is auto generated using Razotr. I was trying the get apply the logic on the check boxes inside each unique `<ul>`

Comment: Try giving them an ID first using `each()`. Have you done that before?